# What is this "beyond"?

Tags: prepositions, literature

> Fred grew eloquent in describing how **hill beyond hill** was covered with the brilliant blossoms of the gorse, and how walking over them was like walking through flames of fire.
>   [Source](https://encrypted.google.com/books?id=UYo-AQAAMAAJ&q=%22hill%20beyond%20hill%20was%22&dq=%22hill%20beyond%20hill%20was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z5iEU7SOBYr68QWgoIGwDA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA)

Is "hill beyond hill" the same as "hill after hill"?

Is it possible to say, **"meadow beyond rolling meadow spread in all directions in front of my eyes."?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is basically the same as saying "hill after hill" or "one hill after another"; it's just a somewhat more poetic-sounding construction.

It doesn't quite work for "meadow beyond meadow" because hills are relatively well-defined things with a clear boundary between the end of one and the start of the next, so they can easily be visualized in a line, while a meadow doesn't necessarily have any specific boundary as part of its normal definition; it could be fenced, it could run into a lake or river, or up against a forest or highway, or up to the edge of a cliff; if there isn't some boundary (either specified or imagined), then it's really just one gigantic meadow spreading in all directions.
(You could probably get away with saying it by citing "poetic license", though.)

Comment: Yes, that would be a perfectly fine usage.  Even something like "Hour beyond hour of mind-numbing, back-breaking toil passed as the chain gang sweated out their sentences in the Louisiana sun."